# python encode and decode with utf-16

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode, utf-16

```
>>>> enbytes = b'\xdf\x81\x9e\xbf"Q\xa37\xd0\x7f\x18\x1d:J\xe2\xa1'

>>>> enbytes.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-16')

b'\xff\xfe\xdf\x81\x9e\xbf"Q\xa37\xd0\x7f\x18\x1d:J\xe2\xa1'
```

why `enbytes` does not equal encoding bytes. How to fix that.

Comment: The output contains two bytes of [BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the byte-order mark (BOM), you can just use a specific endianessto prevent the addition of the BOM, so little endian:

```
>>> enbytes.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-16-le')
b'\xdf\x81\x9e\xbf"Q\xa37\xd0\x7f\x18\x1d:J\xe2\xa1'
>>> enbytes == enbytes.decode('utf-16').encode('utf-16-le')
True
```